# Unfortunate spacing in references and appendix tables of content

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

References and appendix appearing after the chapter, and should be separate.  I don't know what is happening but my referencing and appendix are appearing below Future works(chapter 7) and should be seperate. Can someone please help me correct this?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{latexsym,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=1pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\tb}[1]{\noindent \textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textbf{Tom:}  #1}} 
\newcommand{\ishaan}[1]{\noindent \textcolor{Orange}{\textbf{Ishaan:}  #1}}


\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=2.0cm, top=2cm, bottom=2.0cm}

\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Algorithm}{Algorithm}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}
\numberwithin{Definition}{section}
\numberwithin{Lemma}{section}
\numberwithin{Algorithm}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% Remove the spaces from above , and be neat align, though these need to be edited. 
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
%  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{4pt}%
%  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{4pt}%
%  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{4pt}%
%  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{4pt}}
%\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}



% *********************************************************************
% Headings , and page layout
% *********************************************************************
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % to design my own headings
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc} % to design my own toc , and part/chapter/section styles

% page style of "chapter"
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge \bfseries}
    {\Large Chapter \thechapter \thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\titlerule\vspace{1ex}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0ex}{5ex}{5ex}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\LARGE \bfseries}
    {\thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0ex}{0ex}{2ex}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]{\Large \bfseries}
    {\thispagestyle{plain}}{0ex}{\vspace{2ex}}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0ex}{0ex}{3ex}



% definition of headings
\fancypagestyle{memo}{
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.5pt}
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{I am sorry} 
\chapter{I am sorry again} 

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliography{literature.bib}


\appendix

\newpage
\section{Appendix A}
\label{app:one}

\section{Appendix B}
\label{app:two}

Some other stuff.

\end{document}
```

Comment: your question asks about figures and tables and comments on the appendices being misplaced with chapters, but your code has no tables or figures or chapters? How does it relate to your question?

Comment: Sorry I got the title of question wrong

Comment: OK but still what is your question? You posted a lot of code but almost none of it is actually used in your example which just produces two section headings and one line of text.  You just describe the spacing as "Unfortunate" but that means nothing to anyone else it just means it is not the spacing that you expect. I can not guess what spacing you want to change here.

Comment: You talk about chapters but your MWE has no `\chapter` commands. I have no idea what your problem is. --- GOM

Comment: there is a an unfortunate spacing occuring in the tables of content. The references and appendix are appearing beneath the last chapter, which is making it appear that it is the last chapter and not references and appendix as seperate. I had attached an image, but it does not appear.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. Even while i have posted and continue to post these questions is because I am a learner.

Comment: No it;s fine to be a learner, that is the point of the site, but even a learner can make sure that the code they post has some connection to the question that they want answering. Even now after your edit why does your code include `\usepackage{xcolor}` does the problem not happen without color. Why does it have  `\newtheorem{Algorithm}{Algorithm}` when there is no algorithm in the document shown, is that line needed to show your issue? If not why is it in this question?

Comment: conversely if your question is about the table of contents, why does your posted test document have no table of contents?

Answer (score 1):

In the report class (and pretty much every other LaTeX class which has chapters), appendices are chapters and not sections. When you type `\appendix`, you're putting LaTeX into appendix mode which indicates that the top-level sectioning unit (chapters in book/report and their relatives, sections in article and its relatives) should be treated as an appendix. Other formatting changes may occur as well, depending on the document class.

Most likely you want to change those `\section` commands to `\chapter`s.

Likewise, in report, the references will be produced as a chapter-level sectioning unit. By writing

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
```

what you're doing is adding an extra line (as a section-level toc entry and with the wrong page number as well) to the table of contents. Unfortunately, the definition of how the bibliography is printed in the report class doesn't add a table of contents entry and isn't very friendly for adding a table of contents. The easiest way to make this happen is to change your `\addcontentsline` to be:

```
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
```

The `\clearpage` will make sure that you're on the right page when the page number is output¹ and the `\addcontentsline` has been modified to give the references TOC entry as a chapter rather than a section.

Ideally, though, you should have a document class which automatically adds the table of contents to the table of contents.

**Additional note** as David Carlisle and others indicated, you should really have a minimal working example. I had to make some changes to the copy I used to test my results (in particular, adding a `\tableofcontents` and removing some packages that caused errors when I put a minimal bibliography with a `thebibliography` environment into the document.²

---

1. But watch out if you switch to a double-sided layout.
2. To be more honest, you should have removed that. I didn't, I just had LaTeX skip the errors, a dangerous practice I don't recommend for most users, especially not learners.

Comment: double sided layout? Could you point me where I have done that? I think I have significant errors in my preamble. Thank you for all your help, sir!

Comment: @Jimjamlorde look at the first line of your document. You specify `twoside` as an option on `\documentclass`.